# Вопрос по табам

Tags: android

Добрый день. У меня есть код для табов:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new MondayFragment(), "ПН");
    ...
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); }
```

Как мне назначить таб по умолчанию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(yout viewPager).setCurrentItem(item number); для viewPager
(your tab).setCurrentTab(item number); для TabLayout
```

Примерно так. Если по умолчанию, то в OnCreate делаете нужное вам значение.